# MVC 4 [Authorize] is denying every user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, authorize-attribute

I restarted my production webserver tonight because it was seeming slow.  Since it has come back up, no users are able to get to any views with the [Authorize] attribute on them.

**There has been absolutely no code changes since November.  Not a single tweak or modification of any kind.**  I'm using the SqlMembership provider and I originally thought the issue was there with the login, but I can see that the call to MembershipProvider.ValidateUser() passes successfully (looked at a SQL trace as well as some logging).  After login, I redirect the user to a view decorated with [Authorize] and get denied.

One thing to note that even makes this more strange is that if I register a new user (who gets logged in as part of the user creation process), they are able to get to [Authorize] pages just fine.  But if they log out, they are unable to access the [Authorize] pages once they log back in.

I'm pulling my hair out on this one.  My production site is down and literally the only thing I did was a simple server restart.  I've searched around for hours and at this point have no clue what to even look into next.

If anybody has a some ideas I'd greatly appreciate them - I'm at a complete loss and have a ton of users impacted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few windows updates later the issue fixed itself.  My guess is there was an update applied but pending reboot that hosed everything up when I restarted.  Then when it came back the system found a bunch more windows updates to apply.  I ran through these and it fixed the problem upon the next reboot after these were applied.